# Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/true' could not be found

Tags: wcf

Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/true' could not be found. 
Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.

I already  installed Service Pack 1 for .NET 3.5

```
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/"></add>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetBinding="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>

      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>   
   </configuration>
```

please help where i did mistake?

Answer (score 0):

`httpGetBinding="true"` refers to a binding name, probably you just can remove the httpGetBinding attribute and try the default value. check out: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: if i remove the  httpGetBinding="true" i am getting below error The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service newservices.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.

Comment: i remove httpGetBinding="true" enable the httpGetEnabled="true" HTTP could not register URL http://+:8081/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace error occured..